# PostgreSQL - how to find top routes (records where 2 columns are the same)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, count, sql-order-by

I have a simple Ruby On Rails app that manages trips. Here's an example of data I store in the DB:

```
id | origin     | destination | ...
 1 | London, UK | Prague, CZ  | ...
 2 | Paris, FR  | Berlin, GE  | ...
 3 | Berlin, GE | Munich, GE  | ...
 4 | Berlin, GE | Moscow, RU  | ...
 5 | Rome, IT   | Florence, IT  | ...
 6 | London, UK | Prague, CZ  | ...
 7 | Paris, FR  | Berlin, GE  | ...
 8 | Paris, FR  | Berlin, GE  | ...
```

I'd like to find the top trips, so the desired output is something like this:

```
Paris, FR  | Berlin, GE  | 3x
London, UK | Prague, CZ  | 2x
Berlin, GE | Munich, GE  | 1x
Berlin, GE | Moscow, RU  | 1x
Rome, IT   | Florence, IT  | 1x
```

How do I achieve this? I have a database of 300k trips, for most of the trips I also have stored the lat+long coordinates - but in this case, not sure if it's better to search the origin and destination as strings or rather search the fields through coordinations.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you acheive what? What is the actual metric for "top trips"? The most popular? The one with the most pina coladas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer based on your current database design:

```
Trip.select('origin, destination, count(*) as trips_count')
    .group(:origin, :destination).order('trips_count desc')
```

If you want to include the airlines in query, you can use the [`array_agg`  function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html):

```
Trip.select('origin, destination, count(*) as trips_count, array_agg(distinct(airline)) as airlines')
    .group(:origin, :destination).order('trips_count desc')
```

I would recommend moving the `origin` and `destination` columns into their own table, for instance the `routes` table and replace those columns in the `trips` table with `route_id`. You can also implement a `trips_count` [counter_cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) on the `routes` table and just order by that column to get the most popular routes.

Comment: Hi @AbM, thank you for that! I've used this with some slight modifications. I am just wondering - every trip has a carrier. Within this query, can I list there also the carriers, eg. `Paris, FR  | Berlin, GE  | 3x | Lufthansa, KLM` (in this example, 2 trips conducted KLM, 1 Lufthansa)?

Comment: @user984621I update my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate, count and sort:

```
select origin, destination, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by origin, destination
order by cnt desc
```

Then, you can control the number of routes that the query returns with a `limit` clause. Say you want the 5 most frequent routes, then:

```
select origin, destination, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by origin, destination
order by cnt desc
limit 5
```

Note that this does not take in account potential ties, though. If that's something you are interested in, then the solution depends on your Postgres version. In the latest version (Postgres 13):

```
select origin, destination, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by origin, destination
order by cnt desc
fetch first 5 rows with ties
```

In earlier versions:

```
select origin, destination, cnt
from (
    select origin, destination, count(*) cnt, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable
    group by origin, destination
) t
where rn <= 5
order by cnt desc
```